# Картинка наезжает на надписи при масштабе 150%

Tags: html, css

```css
.gradik {
    background: rgb(244,240,240);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(244,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(71,71,166,1) 23%, rgba(167,167,167,1) 54%);
    min-height: 100vh;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin: 0;}
div {padding: 30px 0}
form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.d1 {background: #ffffff;}
.d1 input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #F9F0DA;
  color: #9E9C9C;
}
.d1 button {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background: #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.d1 button:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F9F0DA;
}

.d1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.typologo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -35%;
    position: absolute;
}
.hmmmmm {
  padding-left:110%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.hmmmm {
  padding-left:135%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.hmmm {
  padding-left:155%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.class {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.ihihih {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.arondomdom {
  position: absolute;;
}
.razmer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 700px;
}
.razmer1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
.arondomdom {
  margin-top: 500px;
  margin-left: -175px;

}
.pochemutak {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tojeotlichniistyli.css">
</head>
<body class="gradik">
    <header>
        <div class="d1">
            <form>  
                <h3 class="hmmmmm">Регистраия</h3>
                <h3 class="hmmmm">Профиль</h3>  
                <h3 class="hmmm">Корзина</h3>  
            <img class="typologo" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">    
            <input type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
            <button type="submit"></button>
            </form>
          </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div class="ihihih">
        <div class="class">
        <h3>Главная</h3>
        <h3>Новинки</h3>
        <h3>Предзаказ</h3>
        <h3>Скидки</h3>
        <h3>Испытай удачу</h3>
        <h3>HAPPY HOUR</h3>
        <h3>Раздача</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="arondomdom">
        <img class="razmer" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
            <div class="pochemutak">
                <h3>Выгодные деньги</h3>
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

При масштабе 150% большая картинка дуба наезжает на надписи сверху

Comment: У .arondomdom убрать  position:static; и margin-top: 0; и всё будет норм

Comment: Так у меня нет ни position:static; ни margin-top:0

Answer (score 0):

Вот полностью исправленный код

```
.gradik {
    background: rgb(244,240,240);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(244,240,240,1) 0%, rgba(71,71,166,1) 23%, rgba(167,167,167,1) 54%);
    min-height: 100vh;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body{margin: 0;}
div {padding: 30px 0}
form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.d1 {background: #ffffff;}
.d1 input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  background: #F9F0DA;
  color: #9E9C9C;
}
.d1 button {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  right: 0px;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  border: none;
  background: #7BA7AB;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.d1 button:before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F9F0DA;
}

.d1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.typologo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -35%;
    position: absolute;
}
.hmmmmm {
  padding-left:110%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.hmmmm {
  padding-left:135%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.hmmm {
  padding-left:155%;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: smaller;
}
.class {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.ihihih {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.razmer {
  height: 410px;
  width: 700px;
  float: left;
}
.razmer1 {
  height: 107px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
}
.pochemutak {
  width: 1px;
}
.perviyrazspanispolzuu {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 300px;
}
.arondomdom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tojeotlichniistyli.css">
</head>
<body class="gradik">
    <header>
        <div class="d1">
            <form>  
                <h3 class="hmmmmm">Регистраия</h3>
                <h3 class="hmmmm">Профиль</h3>  
                <h3 class="hmmm">Корзина</h3>  
            <img class="typologo" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">    
            <input type="text" placeholder="Искать здесь...">
            <button type="submit"></button>
            </form>
          </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div class="ihihih">
        <span class="class">
        <h3>Главная</h3>
        <h3>Новинки</h3>
        <h3>Предзаказ</h3>
        <h3>Скидки</h3>
        <h3>Испытай удачу</h3>
        <h3>HAPPY HOUR</h3>
        <h3>Раздача</h3>
        </span>
        <span class="arondomdom">
        <img class="razmer" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
            <span class="pochemutak">
                <span class="perviyrazspanispolzuu"><h3>Выгодные деньги</h3></span>
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
                <img class="razmer1" src="https://memepedia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/mudroe-tainstvennoe-derevo-mem-9-1.jpg">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </main>
    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).